# design login details in android

Tags: android

I m developing an app which needs login to enter the app. I m trying to show the logged user details as same like facebook login which i displayed below. I tried more but cant get any idea. Can anyone help me to get idea that which layout can we use to acheive this.

[image]

Comment: That is not a screenshot of the Facebook login screen. What is your problem?

Comment: This is not login page, This is profile view page. I need to show the user details like the above screenshot(for half of the screen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you can find the answer here

https://github.com/darvds/RibbonMenu

this is a navigation menu for Android (based on Google+ app)

you can use it as a start

Answer (score 0):

You can use this link-
http://jsharkey.org/blog/2008/08/18/separating-lists-with-headers-in-android-09/

In this you will be able to manage headers of both the listviews.For the above listview insert imageview,textview and imageview in its layout and inflate it in adapter and in the below listview insert imageview, textview in its layout.

This will surely help you.